# lambda condition doesn't work

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, lambda

I'm trying to add a condition to my lambda expression.
So I'm wanting to add a max of 10 books in stock and max 3 books per user.

Here is what I have tried until now. I was able to add only 3 books but I cant add more if I have let say, 5 harry potters and my max is 10.

```
public bool LessBooks4u(RequestViewModel request)
{
     var requestQuery = db.Requests.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BookID == request.BookId);
     if (requestQuery==null && request.Quantity < 10)                             
     {
         return true;
     }
     else 
         return false;          
}
```

I'm guessing that I need to use group by or something to compare?

Comment: `requestQuery == null || request.Quantity < 10` is suitable

Comment: The "doesn't work" in the title of this question, what exactly doesn't work? Is the result of the Lambda function at fault or can't you compile the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i have got it right you have used this `requestQuery` to check that the  user has already requested the same book before. You checked for its value and if it's `null` than he's not. But the problem with this condition is that it doesn't allow your user to add more than one book. You can use `Count()` method instead and you do not really need this redundant `if{} else{}` statements as your lical operation already returns bool result. Your method can be something like this :

```
public bool LessBooks4u(RequestViewModel request)
{
     return db.Requests.Count(b => b.BookID == request.BookId) < 3 && request.Quantity < 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You complicated your expression. You can do it a lot easier with [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Bb535181(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
var totalCount = db.Requests.Count(x=>x.BookID == request.BookId);
return totalCount < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to check if books quantity in db is less than 10. Just replace `&&` to `||`

```
public bool LessBooks4u(RequestViewModel request)
{
     var requestQuery = db.Requests.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BookID == request.BookId);
     return requestQuery == null || request.Quantity < 10;               
}
```